# Strange whitespace missing on a regex

Tags: php, regex

I have this kind of regex on PHP :

```
$str="first word https://www.helloz.it last word";
$str=preg_replace(
    '#[^"](((http|https|ftp)://)[^\s\n]+)#',
    '<a class="lforum" href="$1">$1</a>',
    $str);
echo nl2br($str);
```

And the output that I'll expect is :

```
first word <a class="lforum" href="https://www.helloz.it">https://www.helloz.it</a> last word
```

but in fact the output is :

```
first word<a class="lforum" href="https://www.helloz.it">https://www.helloz.it</a> last word
```

(notice the missing whitespace between `first word` and `<a class...`

Where is it vanished that whitespace? :) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[^"]` says "match a character that isn't `"`".  A space character is matched by this, so it is replaced by your regex.

Use a negative lookbehind instead:

```
'#(?<!")(((http|https|ftp)://)[^\s\n]+)#',
```

This says "match the string if it doesn't follow a quotation mark".  Preceding characters are not therefore included in your matched content.

See [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind) for information about lookbehinds.

Answer (score 1):

`[^"]` matches the whitespace and you replace the entire match which removes the whitespace. Put it within `()` and put it back first in the new string.